# How do I set the text format used in a message (from the Message module)?

Tags: 7, input-formats, message-subscribe

I'm using the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module on a site that has both the Filtered HTML and Full HTML text formats. By default, Message appears to use Filtered HTML, but I would like to use Full HTML instead.

However, I couldn't find an option for changing text formats in the UI. I have exported my message types to a feature using the Features module, so instead I tried changing the format from "filtered_html" to "full_html" in the feature and reverting, but this didn't work, either.

Is is possible to change the text format used to display messages, and if so, how?

(Also [asked in the module's issue queue](http://drupal.org/node/1965056).  When I get an answer, I will update both.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to change the format, but I was able to get what I wanted by modifying the text format itself (then I had to adjust everything else that was using the text format in another way).  Not an ideal solution, but it worked for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the permission for user role to use filtered_html or full_html in Administer -> people -> permission.

Comment: I'm created the message types with the user 1 account, which has all permissions.  Still, this alone does not allow me to set the text format for the message.

Answer (score 0):

Comment #1 in the issue you linked to contains "a" way to do what you're looking for:

> ... you can select the text format in the ui while writing the message text.

That same issue also contains a [screenprint](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/Edit_user_changes_profile_information___Drupal7_Testsuite-3.png) about this, which looks like so:

[image]